# Is there any way or pattern to avoid this kind of java code duplication

Tags: java, design-patterns, duplicates

Hi i want to know if there are some pattern to avoid code repetition and ifs in cases like this for Java.

```
public void updateSequence( DN dn, long seq, long countDescriptorId, int mode ) {
    Collection<ResyncNECountSequenceDescriptor> sequencesCollection = 
        sequences.get( dn );
    ResyncNECountSequenceDescriptor neDescSeq = 
        new ResyncNECountSequenceDescriptor( countDescriptorId, seq );
    if ( sequencesCollection != null && sequencesCollection.size() > 0 ) {
        boolean foundSeq = false;
        for ( ResyncNECountSequenceDescriptor sequence : sequencesCollection ) {
            if ( sequence.getCountDescriptorId() == countDescriptorId ) {
                if ( mode == LAST_CREATED_DATFILE_SEQUENCE ) {
                    sequence.setLastCreatedDatfileSequence( seq );
                } else {
                    if ( seq > sequence.getLastCreatedDatfileSequence() ) {
                        seq = 0;
                    }
                    sequence.setNextDatfileToProcessSequence( seq );
                }
                foundSeq = true;
            }
        }
        if ( !foundSeq ) {
            sequencesCollection.add( neDescSeq );
        }
    } else {
        Collection<ResyncNECountSequenceDescriptor> col = new 
            ArrayList<ResyncNECountSequenceDescriptor>();
        col.add( neDescSeq );
        sequences.putIfAbsent( dn, col );
    }
}
```

In this method for example, I want to get rid of the mode parameter and do two methods instead. The thing is only thing that changes is the inner if condition and logic, but all the rest is identical. How to avoid or minimize code duplication in this case ?

Comment: Well the easiest way would be to make this method `private`, then make two new `public` methods which don't use `mode`. Have each of those two methods call this one with the proper `mode` instead. I'm not sure if this satisfies your requirements, however.

Comment: Please post a minimal example, I can hardly read the code

Comment: You can pass a lambda to define what operation to perform.

Answer (score 0):

- Optimize readability first. Only optimize for runtime performance only if there is a good reason to. "premature optimization is the root of all evil in programming"
- Have a separate `SequenceCollection` class so you can push domain logic to it; You may decide whether it should compose or inherit from `ArrayList`. For the sake of simplicity (I don't know the rest of you code) I did the latter. But usually you should favor composition over interitance.
- Use an upsert function that takes a Lambda in order to get rid of duplication
- Don't use parameters such as `mode`. These are [control couplings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) (which is bad).
- Push business logic such as the sequence number overflow to the setter ([Tell, don't Ask](http://www.principles-wiki.net/principles:Tell%20Don%27t%20Ask/Information%20Expert))
- In general factor out separately understandable functionality into separate methods.

This is the result:

```
private Map<DN, SequenceCollection> sequences;

class SequenceCollection extends ArrayList<ResyncNECountSequenceDescriptor> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void upsert(long countDescriptorId, long seqNumber,
            Consumer<ResyncNECountSequenceDescriptor> updateFunction) {
        Optional<ResyncNECountSequenceDescriptor> sequence = findByCountDescriptorId(countDescriptorId);
        if (sequence.isPresent()) {
            updateFunction.accept(sequence.get());
        } else {
            this.add(new ResyncNECountSequenceDescriptor(countDescriptorId, seqNumber));
        }
    }

    public Optional<ResyncNECountSequenceDescriptor> findByCountDescriptorId(long countDescriptorId) {
        return this.stream() //
                .filter(seq -> seq.getCountDescriptorId() == countDescriptorId) //
                .findAny();
    }
}

class DN {
}

class ResyncNECountSequenceDescriptor {
    private long seqNumber;

    public ResyncNECountSequenceDescriptor(long countDescriptorId, long seq) {
    }

    public long getCountDescriptorId() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void setLastCreatedDatfileSequence(long seq) {
    }

    public long getLastCreatedDatfileSequence() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void setNextDatfileToProcessSequence(long seqNumber) {
        if (seqNumber > getLastCreatedDatfileSequence()) {
            seqNumber = 0;
        }
        this.seqNumber = seqNumber;
    }
}

public void updateLstCreatedSequence(DN dn, long seqNumber, long countDescriptorId) {
    SequenceCollection sequenceCollection = getSequenceCollection(dn);
    sequenceCollection.upsert(countDescriptorId, seqNumber, seq -> seq.setLastCreatedDatfileSequence(seqNumber));
}

private SequenceCollection getSequenceCollection(DN dn) {
    return sequences.computeIfAbsent(dn, k -> new SequenceCollection());
}

public void updateNextSequence(DN dn, long seqNumber, long countDescriptorId) {
    SequenceCollection sequenceCollection = getSequenceCollection(dn);
    sequenceCollection.upsert(countDescriptorId, seqNumber, seq -> seq.setNextDatfileToProcessSequence(seqNumber));
}
```